# Attributeerror: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Input'

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, attributeerror

I am using Tensorflow 1.14. In my Python code, there is a line as follows:

```
x = tf.Input(shape=(max_length, charset_length))
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Attributeerror: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Input'
```

But based on the API, this attribute exits. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think there is.  Where do you see it?   https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf

Comment: You probably need to use tf.keras.Input if you are trying to instantiate a Keras tensor to be used as input in a keras Model.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_length, charset_length))
```

And it worked.